# If $z = 1 + i$, plotting the powers $z^j$ for $j = 1,2,3,\ldots,10$ on an Argand diagram. Is there a pattern?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z = 1 + i$, calculate the powers $z^j$ for $j = 1,2,3,\ldots,10$ and plot them on an Argand diagram.

I understand how to do this and I'm sure after some tedious work you **can** do this, however my interest is in whether a certain pattern arises from this plotting and if so, why?

Additionally I wonder what would the smallest positive integer $n$ be such that $z^n$ is a real number?

Comment: Note that $(1+i)^2=2i$ and so the smallest $n$ for which $z^n=(1+i)^n$ is a real number is what?

Comment: To the last question, does $n=0$ count?  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pattern:

[image]

The general graph of $(1+i)^n$ is given by, for $n\ge0$,

[image]

or,

> $$(1+i)^n=2^{n/2}(\cos\frac{n\pi}4+i\sin\frac{n\pi}4)$$

Comment: Wow, nicely done.

Comment: @juniven Thanks!  :D  (I didn't actually graph that with a complex graphing calculator.  Just some polar magic)

Comment: How would you describe this pattern? ;)

Comment: @TripleA see the last line.

Comment: @SimpleArt As in, how would you write in words or describe the pattern?

Comment: @TripleA oh, well, angle and distance from origin.  Plot a table of magnitudes, and I hope my first graph helps.

Comment: For searching purposes: that curve is a *logarithmic spiral*.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Note that $(1+i)^2=2i$.

If $n=2k$ then $(1+i)^{2k}=(2i)^k$;

If $n=2k+1$ then $(1+i)^{2k+1}=(2i)^k(1+i)$.

Also remember that:

1. $i^{4p}=1$
2. $i^{4p+1}=i$
3. $i^{4p+2}=-1$
4. $i^{4p+3}=-i$

Can you finish?